# how can i create and use multiple terminal configurations simultaneously?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

is there a way to set multiple sets of preferences for pantheon terminal, and invoke multiple instances using different preferences?

thanks,
Dan

Comment: What do you mean with "preferences"? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible, in current version of `pantheon-terminal`, to have multiple "user profiles", what I believe is the "preferences" you're asking.

If you really need it, a good option is the `gnome-terminal` that have this feature. (and it's written in gtk so it doesn't look too diferent from the rest of elementary OS)

Just install via

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal -y
```

Change your preferences in `Edit > Profile Preferences` menu. Save multiple preferences in `Edit > Profiles...`

If you want to use it as the default terminal, run

```
sudo update-alternative --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and select it from the list.